# Can I have multiple controller inside1 Div in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

In Angular JS, I have a section of form where I want to use 2 different controllers. Can I have multiple controllers inside 1 directive like this?

```
<form ng-controller="DatePickerController FileUploadController">
```

I tried the above and its not working. Is this not allowed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ng-controller directive creates a $scope for the element it's on. The text inside ng-controller references the specific namespace you bound your controller code to. So this would be the equivalent of trying to find your `myApp["DatePickerController FileUploadController"]` controller. **Not going to work**.

There's also a second thing I've noticed: you're referencing datepicker and fileupload controllers. To me, both of those sound like directives. Controllers are for views - aka they control the layout of a particular page. Directives are for adding functionality to your HTML, like date picking and file uploading.

I would take a look at http://ngmodules.org/, they should have the functionality you need in the correct format.

Answer (score 1):

No as it's written this can't be done.  See the snippet below from the documents.  You could write a constructor function that creates each of those controllers and abstracts the scope function calls but as is there is no way to do this (I think this may be a bit of a mess since you have to determine where to resolve a particular method if both controllers contain it and maybe other problems)

> ngController - expression - Name of a globally accessible constructor function or an expression that on the current scope evaluates to a constructor function. The controller instance can be published into a scope property by specifying as propertyName.